# differences in routing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes, request

how you doing,
I have just started learning Laravel, and I have question about routing
I have written this code

```
Route::get('/articles/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){
    return 'article id:' . $id;
});

Route::get('/articles/{id}', function($id){
    return 'article id:' . $id;
});


Route::get('/articles/{parameter}', function($id){
    return 'article id:' . $id;
});
```

the three previous routes give the same Result

and the next two routes give the same result as well

```
Route::get('/article/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){

    return view('article');
});


Route::get('/article/{id}', function(){
    return view('article');
});
```

So I do not under stand why should we pass request to routing function since it works without any need of adding the request,

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Passing the ```Request $request``` is important when you are sending a ```POST``` request. Maybe through a form. In your examples above, they are all ```GET``` routes, so it makes no difference

Comment: The Request also holds info (host, path ...) not available in your `$id` parameter. If you don't need any of those you don't need to pass `$request`. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests should help

Comment: Now i got it, thanks friends for helping.

Comment: You get to pass whatever class you want if you need it and Laravel will inject it for you e.g. you can do things like `Route::get('/article/{id}', function(MyService $service, MyOtherService $service2, Request $request){` and Laravel inject them as parameters to your route handler if it is able to. `Request` is just the most often shown example because it's the one most people usually would need to do at some point in their app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the `$request` is optional and you don't even have to pass it, you can just use the `request()` helper instead.

If you do pass it, it uses Laravel automatic dependency injection.